# Tips and suggestions for storing pdf files in server or database using java spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am confused were to store the PDF file s either in database like mysql or in server like apache tomcat by creating folder and storing files according to performance which is the best option in a scenario like  500 users accessing PDF files simultaneously pls help me.

Comment: Not the right place for this question.
Ask it here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the bast way is to use file system. If you are on linux you can put all the document in one directory. In NTFS file system create a hierarchy of directory using a pattern like year/month/day of the pdt and reference its path in mysql. 
For apache it'll be static resources and you'll have the best performances.